# Does overclocking have any benefit on a processor that already has Intel Turbo Boost?

Tags: cpu, performance, overclocking, core

I've read that when the model number of an Intel Core i5 or i7 processor ends in K, it means that it is "unlocked" and can be manually overclocked by the end user. These processors also come with Turbo Boost, which automatically increases the clock speed above the base speed when certain thresholds are met.

Is there any benefit in specifically getting a K-version Core processor and overclocking it, when most Core processors already come with Turbo Boost and therefore automatically overclock themselves to some extent when needed?

Comment: depends on how much you want to overclock and how much the turbo boost raises the clock speed to, and if there is a limit and delay on it.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of an unlocked processor is that you get fine-grained control over the clock multiplier.

The clock multiplier is only one of several variables adjusted when practicing the art of over clocking. Years ago, before CPU manufactures locked multipliers, malicious people would buy cheaper clocked CPUs, change the multiplier and sell the computers as faster models. To prevent this, manufactures made it harder to overclock by locking the multiplier.

CPUs with unlocked multipliers are primarilly targeted towards people doing extreme over-clocking, (like with liquid nitrogen). You will be spending 10% more money for 1-5% more performance.

tl;dr You most likely will be better off spending that money on a better hard drive, than the marginal increases those CPUs will give you.